# How to avoid failure and bring back more items home?

Tags: recettear-an-item-shops-tale

It seems to me that it's highly inefficient to spent two parts of the day on retrieving one item.

How do I bring back more items home?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways to bring back more items home.

- **Stop dying**! If you make it to the end of a sequence (which will have a nice big red door), then you can return home with all of the items in your bag. Unless you found something *really* nice in a particular run that you must keep that one item, it is basically preferable to just reload your game and retry the dungeon so that you can clear it and return home.

  If you're having trouble, then what you should do is **start bringing items with you**. Bring equipment to better suit your adventurer, especially armor. And bring ample amounts of food. You'll get food along the way, but starting with food ensures that you'll have enough. Yes, bringing items along (especially equipment) will reduce the number of items you can carry. But in the end, returning home with only 16 items is *much* better than returning home with only 1.
- **Get a better Merchant Level**. As you progress in Merchant Levels, it is possible to increase the number of items you can bring home on failure to 2 and even 3. It's still preferable to make it to the end, but this can still make things more manageable, especially when you are in dungeons where death is a lot harder to avoid.